# RESTful Web application- Session data management

Tags: rest

We are developing an application having many screens. Each screen data is coming from Rest API. What the best practice to store the session data(screen data) at backed?

For example- I need data of screen two(includes the screen input data and response from rest API) in 4th screen. For this I want to store the rest response of screen two in server side.

I came of with two scenarios for this, if anyone has experience please help:
1) Session management using REDIS-- but this is mostly used in clustering environment.
2) Session management using spring security and spring session management.

Please suggest the better way of doing it.

Details:
Spring-boot application will be hosted in cloud
Also the question is not related to security, authentication, authorization.

Kindly help me with best practice to move the data to different screens.

Answer (score 2):

> For example- I need data of screen two(includes the screen input data and response from rest API) in 4th screen. For this I want to store the rest response of screen two in server side.

What you are describing there is a violation of the [Stateless](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3) architectural constraint of REST.

The "right" answer is to take one of two approaches; one is to store the "session data" on the client -- the server sends the data back to the client (for example, as fixed/hidden fields in the form) in the response.  The other is to use the client actions to modify a resource (think shopping cart).

The core problem is this: the stateless constraint means that the server is only operating on the current request; the server only ever sees requests, not state changes (ex: the client can hit the back button, or otherwise jump to some other state in its history, or fetch additional state from somewhere else).

If you use the "modify a resource" approach, you may want to review [RFC 7232: Conditional Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), and think about whether or not your use case needs to worry about the "lost update problem".

Comment: But in my case the data is huge around 1MB. So i dont want to store the data of screens at client side. What how do I approach this?